# /etc/fstab behaviour in Redhat 7.2

Tags: linux, redhat

I changed the /boot mount point to /dummy in /etc/fstab entry.
Then I rebooted, I was expecting the boot failure. But instead, it booted. And all the contents of /boot has been copied to /dummy directory and /boot directory is empty.
Even I commented the /boot entry in /etc/fstab, but still it booted.

```
OS is Redhat 7.2
```

I dont understand this!! why did this automatically copied contents of /boot to /dummy ?

Comment: `/boot` is actually not required to be mounted. Grub doesn't care about mount points because grub boots the system before there is even a kernel running to mount things.

Comment: ok. But if a mount point doesnt exist to mount, does it automatically creates one and copy the contents of that disk. Here contents of /boot was copied to a directory which was automatically created while creating.

Comment: Are you sure it is Red Hat 7.2? That version was released in 2001 and discontinued a few years later.

Comment: Unless I see evidence of kernel 2.4 I tend to assume Red Hat Linux is incorrectly referencing RHEL. Only a few more years before RHEL 10 when the numbers become unambiguous...

Comment: @kasperd Yes it is RedHat 7.2 (Maipo)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a *copy* of the files, it is a *mount* point!

The Description of command [`mount`(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) tells it all:

> All files accessible in a Unix system are arranged in one big tree,
>   the file hierarchy, rooted at `/`. These files can be spread out over
>   several devices. The `mount` command serves to attach the filesystem
>   found on some device to the big file tree. Conversely, the [`umount`(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount)
>   command will detach it again.
>
> The standard form of the mount command, is
>
> ```
> mount -t type device dir
> ```
>
> This tells the kernel to attach the filesystem found on *device*
>   (which is of type type) at the directory *dir*. The previous contents
>   (if any) and owner and mode of *dir* become invisible, and as long as
>   this filesystem remains mounted, the pathname *dir* refers to the root
>   of the filesystem on *device*.

Why doesn't GRUB care about this? **GRUB is independent**, tiny and function-specific **OS**. It doesn't care about the operating system or its internal configuration (like `/etc/fstab`) at all. Oracle tells us [How GRUB Based Booting Works](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-2379/fvbse/index.html):

> When the initialization phase has completed, the BIOS loads the boot
>   loader from the configured boot device and then transfers control of
>   the system to the boot loader.
>
> Because GRUB is intuitive about file systems and kernel executable
>   formats, you can load an operating system without recording the
>   physical position of the kernel on the disk. With GRUB-based booting,
>   the kernel is loaded by specifying its file name, and the drive and
>   the partition where the kernel resides. For more information see
>   [Naming Conventions That Are Used for Configuring GRUB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-2379/fvbsh/index.html).

As you can see, this is cited from Solaris documentation. "WTF?", you may ask. It doesn't matter: GRUB can work with Linux, Solaris OS, Windows and many other. That's possible, because it works as described above.

Comment: Ok. If I mention a non existing directory in the /etc/fstab on the place of /boot and rebooted the system what would be the existing the behaviour ? Or can this mount to a non existing directory (by creating it)?

Comment: `mount` (or `fstab`) doesn't create folders automatically. You'll get an error: "Mount point does not exists". Some GUI tools, while mounting, do this check and can perform `mkdir` before `mount`, but that's not a function of `mount`.  _Why?_ [The UNIX Philosophy](http://marmaro.de/docs/studium/unix-phil/unix-phil.pdf) approaches to minimalist, modular software development. Therefore, the basic UNIX commands are deliberately specialized, each performing one general function, and they can interact using _pipes_ and _interfaces_. Read the linked paper by Markus Schnalke and... save the world!

Comment: @exactly, it is not a function of mount. but I am getting this behavior after restart. I am not sure why!!

Comment: @nirmalraj17 Looks like RedHat implement something to create mount point during boot. I saw same behavior on CentOS 7.